# What does it mean "polynomial related"?

Tags: cryptography

Taken from

*Cambridge University Press
0521830842 - Foundations of Cryptography: Basic Applications, Volume 2
CHAPTER FIVE - Encryption Schemes*

which can be downloaded [here](http://bilder.buecher.de/zusatz/21/21269/21269809_lese_1.pdf)

> Notation. In the rest of this text, we
>   write $E_e (\alpha)$ instead of $E(e, \alpha)$ and
>   $D_d (\beta)$ instead of $D(d, \beta)$. Sometimes,
>   when there is little risk of
>   confusion, we drop these subscripts.
>   Also, we let $G_1 (1^n)$ (resp., $G_2 (1^n
>   )$) denote the first (resp., second)
>   element in the pair G(1n ). That is,
>   $G(1n ) = (G_1 (1^n ), G_2 (1^n))$.
>   Without loss of generality, we may
>   assume that $|G_1 (1^n )|$ and $|G_2 (1^n
> > )|$ are **polynomially related to n**,
>   and that each of these integers can be
>   efficiently computed from the other.
>   (In fact, we may even assume that $|G_1
> > (1^n )| = |G_2 (1^n)| = n$; see Exercise
>   6.)

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the functions mentioned in your question can be written as a polynomial in $n$ (the independent variable is $n$). For example, $n^2+3n+4$ or something like that. It cannot be an exponential function or super-polynomial in $n$ or sublinear (i.e. $o(n)$).

Comment: Why can't it be sub-linear?

Comment: I've make a mistake with my words. What I've meant to say was sublinear but logarithmic. It is allowed to have $n^{1/2}$ for example.